# How can I sniff traffic sent by POST method (on another computer)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, sniffing

Suppose there is a site which has a form and it send data through POST method over http **(NOT HTTPS)?**

I can access this website directly and also the victim's computer directly.
How can i sniff what data was sent while posting form on that site by the victim's ip?

OS to be used: ubuntu 9.04

Comment: Is this something we really should be helping with?  It at least sounds malicious.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.
I said that I can access the website and victim's computer directly actually means that the VICTIM is my subnet and the also i can ping the website.

To be precise, my ip address is 10.100.98.73. Victim's ip address is 10.100.98.98(let us suppose). And the website has address 10.100.56.55:8090.
Now, can u help. I tried using Wireshark but how do i see post traffic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) should help you. It is cross platform and allows you to sniff any packet that goes through the wire

Answer (score 3):

The Firebug Extension for Firefox has a very convenient network traffic sniffer built in as well, it will show you all the info about your POST the response as well as what JavaScript functions were running and how long they took to run, all useful stuff when trying to figure out exactly what a website is doing behind the scenes.  More information [here](http://getfirebug.com/net.html).

Comment: Please add the Link :) Its missing

Comment: Won't work in this situation, where the "victim" should not be aware of the sniffing.

Answer (score 2):

Capture the traffic and follow the TCP stream in [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Answer (score 1):

If the victim computer has WireShark installed, then probably you should run "tshark" in a script, save packets in a file and copy/mail the file to wherever you want. You can then open the file using wireshark and follow tcp stream of  whichever connection interests you (HTTP POST ?). This is assuming you have control over the victim computer, WireShark is installed, and you want to capture packets without letting the victim know.

If WireShark is not installed then you can try arp-poisoning (for default gateway) the victim machine and divert all its traffic to you machine (assuming it is connected in the same broadcast domain). Your machine will need to "ip forward" all the traffic coming from victim machine to default gateway.

Answer (score 1):

For a direct browser solution in Firefox (since WireShark has already been mentioned,) take a look at [**HTTPFox**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647) add-on. You can start it then hide it.

[image]

Comment: This only shows the traffic from one's own browser, not from the victim's browser. Aha, but that's why wrote "You can start it then hide it".

Comment: Read the question - "I can access this website directly and also the victim's computer directly."

Comment: True, but I assume the victim should not be aware of the peeking into the traffic. Still, I understand that you propose to hide it on the victim's computer -- just wanted others to understand that too. Here I am, making things much more complicated than they were. :-) (Yup, sorry about that.)