# Is there a way I can check what information a piece of software is sending out

Tags: sniffing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I sniff traffic sent by POST method (on another computer)?](https://superuser.com/questions/52719/how-can-i-sniff-traffic-sent-by-post-method-on-another-computer)

I need to streamline a process for a client. Currently he has some a bit of software which extracts products from a supplier website which he then manually imports into his website to sell. Once the sale is done though, he needs to update the software which then updates the supplier website. Very clunky. There is also no API in this software to integrate more seamlessly.

I need to figure out how to "sniff" the information sent out from this application to supplier site in order to replicate the process, thereby bypassing the software in order for it to be more seamless.

Is it possible to use some software to see what information is leaving the software and in what format in order to duplicate this process?

Many thanks

-------------------------------------------------------------------EDIT

I'm using Windows XP at the moment. Most likely moving onto Win 7 soon.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for most Operating Systems, you will want to use something like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), but, it is certainly not for the novice.

Comment: Thanks William. I actually have Wireshark installed and you're right, it's bloody tricky to learn as a novice. If I do learn/get someone to help, will this work do you think?

Comment: Seems there is a dedicated QA site for this wireshark. http://ask.wireshark.org/